# How to achieve navigation between images with control like instagram stories?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, instagram-story

I'm trying to achieve the navigation between images in a recycler view, like instagram stories; i mean, the white line divided in the number of stories.. and when you click one, u got the image in the position clicked..

I already have the recycler view and i was trying to put an image overlay to simulate the white line but i didn't get good results.

```
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv_evento_images);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, HORIZONTAL, false));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(imagesRecyclerAdapter);
```

My xml:

```
<LinearLayout 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:text="Bar"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_evento_images"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
```

the result needed...

https://ibb.co/znd8vpB

Answer (score 0):

Well I found a solution for future viewers.

I thought that "instagram stories" were a recycler view with images, but no. The control is a view that set the background of an imageview.

I used a library, StoriesProgressView [this one!](https://github.com/shts/StoriesProgressView)

It work very well, but depends what features do u need.